# Getting current value of comboBox in SelectedValueChange event

Tags: c#, winforms

I follow [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21085/CheckBox-ComboBox-Extending-the-ComboBox-Class-and) instructions to create multi select combobox

So I have something like this:

```
 var empList = db.GetTableBySQL($"exec getTaskAssignableEmployeeList");


        checkBoxComboBox1.DataSource = new Utility.ListSelectionWrapper<DataRow>(empList.Rows, "Abbreviation");
        checkBoxComboBox1.DisplayMemberSingleItem = "Name";
        checkBoxComboBox1.DisplayMember = "NameConcatenated";
        checkBoxComboBox1.ValueMember = "Selected";
        checkBoxComboBox1.Tag = empList.Rows;

        checkBoxComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged += ComboEmployee_SelectedValueChanged;
```

As you can see I have `ComboEmployee_SelectedValueChanged` Event. So when I click into one checkbox I want to retrieve value of comboBox as:

```
private void ComboEmployee_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var db = new SQLConnMgr();


            var employeeComboBox = sender as CheckBoxComboBox;
            var taskDataRow = employeeComboBox.Tag as DataRow;
            var taskTypeName = taskDataRow["Name"] as string;
         }
```

But I'm getting error because `taskDataRow` is always null, then when it try to execute `var taskTypeName = taskDataRow["Name"] as string;` I'm getting:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Why I cant retrieve taskDataRow fro\m comboBox? Regards

Comment: checkBoxComboBox1.Tag = empList.Rows; => you set a list of item, howerver you tried to get a single object here employeeComboBox.Tag as DataRow; => it's wrong

Comment: And what should I do to make it work? @HieuLe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know which items are selected, you have two options:

1. Use the `CheckBoxItems` property on the ComboBox which is a list of items wrapping each item in the ComboBox.Items list. The `CheckBoxComboBoxItem` class is a standard CheckBox, and therefore the bool value you are looking for is contained in Checked.
2. Or if you stored a reference to the `ListSelectionWrapper<T>`, you could use that to access the `Selected` property of the binded list.

-

```
if (ComboBox.CheckBoxItems[5].Checked)  
            DoSomething();
```

OR

```
if (StatusSelections.FindObjectWithItem(UpdatedStatus).Selected)
    DoSomething();
```

You are getting Null Reference exception because you have saved table.Rows in the tag of the combobox not the DataRow in the below line that why you are getting exception.

var taskDataRow = employeeComboBox.Tag as DataRow;

> To resolve the issue, Iterate through CheckBoxItems and there you can
>   get the selected item text. After that filter the data rows on the
>   basis of selected item text or value.